# How can a program read its own image from memory via ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make an executable which can read itself from memory using **ReadProcessMemory** api of windows.

Then, I will use this to calculate the checksum of executable.

This is my code :

```
#define PSAPI_VERSION 1
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")


int main(void)
{

    HWND hMyProcess = (HWND)(GetCurrentProcess());
    HMODULE hModule = (HMODULE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
    MODULEINFO moduleInfo;
    if(hModule != NULL && hMyProcess != NULL){
        // if (GetModuleInformation())
        GetModuleBaseName(hMyProcess, hModule, szProcessName, MAX_PATH);
        printf("%s\n", szProcessName);
        if (GetModuleInformation(hMyProcess, hModule, &moduleInfo, sizeof(moduleInfo))){
            printf("lpBaseOfDLL : %x\n", moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll);
            printf("Entry Point : %x\n", moduleInfo.EntryPoint);
            printf("SizeOfImage : %x\n", moduleInfo.SizeOfImage);
        }
    }
    // Till here working fine, problem lies below

    // read process memory
    TCHAR *hexEXE;
    SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead;
    if(ReadProcessMemory(hMyProcess, moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll,
        hexEXE, moduleInfo.SizeOfImage, 0)){
        //printf("%s\n", hexEXE);
        printf("Read memory\n");
        printf("%d \n",strlen(hexEXE));
    }

    // will be implemented later, taken from --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382380(VS.85).aspx
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;

    /*if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_FULL,CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)){
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        //CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash)){
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        //CloseHandle(hFile);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return dwStatus;
    }*/



    return 0;
}
```

### Problem :

I am not able to read the my own process's memory, it's the first time I'm using **WinAPI**, so perhaps I am using the function in some wrong way.

The program just hangs and it shows "Windows has encountered some problem..."

### Possible Reasons of Error :

I think the handle to the process ( **hMyProcess** ) I'm getting earlier isn't with the required privileges ( **PROCESS_VM_READ** ), how do I verify it and if it isn't then how do I get the correct privileges.

Comment: Why, in 2018, use MD5?

Comment: Any better suggestions , although that's not of main concern here, it's for a trial so gtg with it

Comment: I'd go with SHA2-256 at the very last and SHA2-512 if I cared about detecting changes reliably.

Comment: @tadman ok, will do the needful, thanks :)

Comment: what sense use `ReadProcessMemory` for read itself from memory ?! read memory direct

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory(hMyProcess, moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll,
        &hexEXE, moduleInfo.SizeOfImage, 0)` - **`&hexEXE`** !

Comment: @RbMm sorry, I don't get you, the purpose is to read itself from memory and then calculate it's checksum, so as to detect debuggers, I know there are ways to bypass it and also better ways to check it but I want to implement this, if you can help with this thanks .

Comment: You don't need to use `ReadProcessMemory`. You can simply read the memory directly, the way you would read any memory.

Comment: @RbMm I tried **&hexEXE** too, but the printf's don't trigger, i.e. the `if` condition still remains false .

Comment: use `ReadProcessMemory` exist sense use for read memory for **another** process. for read memory of current process - it not need

Comment: *I tried &hexEXE too* - and this is error

Comment: @RbMm ok , I get it, how do I read memory directly ?

Comment: @hemo - *how do I read memory directly* - very strange question

Comment: @hemo you have no clue about how windows exe works and looks in memory after it's executed, also you want to use ReadProcessMemory to read from memory of own process? You clearly need to educate yourself, you're not gonna achieve anything without basic knownledge, not even simple md5 checksum

Comment: @RbMm, I may sound silly ( which I believe I am ), but what do you mean by the above comment "I tried &hexEXE too - and this is error "

Comment: @hemo that's how stuff works - you can copypaste many things from stackoverflow, but you can't copypaste your way through everything you want whenever you want, it's like you want to solve integral eq without knowing how to multiply two numbers

Comment: @RbMm I mean it's not that I've to read a single point of memory, rather the whole chunk of memory, I thought there is some shortcut for that so asked, instead of iterating over using a loop like `&address` ...

Comment: @hemo you're not gonna receive here any copypaste friendly code, at first I was going to paste you some snippets but now I clearly see you don't have clue about what you want to do

Comment: @RbMm oh sorry man, I get it , it was silly **&hexEXE**, but that still doesn't work, I get it that I can read the process memory iterating over addresses but why doesn't it work ?

Comment: @hemo: We are not a tutoring site. Please get the basics and read [ask]. Edit your question according to the rules and don't use comments for extended discussion or follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR *hexEXE;
SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead;
hexEXE = malloc (moduleInfo.SizeOfImage);
if(ReadProcessMemory(hMyProcess, moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll,
    hexEXE, moduleInfo.SizeOfImage, 0)){
    //printf("%s\n", hexEXE);
    printf("Read memory\n");
    //hexEXE is not a string. Don't use it in strlen.
    //printf("%d \n",strlen(hexEXE));
    print("%d \n", moduleInfo.SizeOfImage);
}
```

The ReadProcessMemory need a memory to store the image. So, the "hexEXE" need be assign to a memory buffer.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the extended discussion, but I got it running by changing the code to instead of using **ReadProcessMemory** directly iterating over the memory through a *for loop* like this :

```
 long *baseAddress = (long *)moduleInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
    printf("%d %x\n",baseAddress, baseAddress);
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleInfo.SizeOfImage; ++i){
        long *addressToRead = baseAddress+i;
        printf("%x : %x\n", addressToRead, *addressToRead);
    }
```

Here's the output :

[image: This is the output]

### Further thoughts

However, I don't understand why am I not able to get it using **ReadProcessMemory**.

Comment: Anyone who's downvoted this, can you please comment what's wrong with this, I don't know how to properly print it but that's not my concern

Comment: (Not my vote) It might not be _your_ concern, but at least 2 people seem to think that pictures of text are a bad idea. That said - "extended discussion" is also a red flag on a pure Question&Answers site.

Comment: You seem to be asking a question in this answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm actually unclear of one point and thought it would be better if someone might answer that

Comment: @MSalters I took pictures of text to make it clear, nothing unintended